# Word Chain (Word-ladder?)

Tags: word-ladder, pencil-and-paper-games

You've heard of the change LEAD to GOLD by changing one letter at a time. A player has suggested another, and we're having a hard time with it. **BITTER** to **SWEETS.**

Comment: Is there a certain dictionary we should use?

Comment: The urban dictionary

Comment: standard English, even British English is fine. There's a group of six to eight playing a word at a time. Any hints would be great.

Comment: I see two answers. Awesome, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it in 10 jumps (all definitions come from Merriam-Webster)

> BITTER
>  BETTER
>  [SETTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/setter)
>  [SEATER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seater)
>  [SLATER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slater)
>  [SLATES](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slates) (as a verb)
>  [SLANES](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slanes)
>  [SLANTS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slants)
>  [SLENTS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slents)
>  [SLEETS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleets) (as a verb)
>  SWEETS

Answer (score 1):

> BITTER BETTER SETTER SEATER SLATER SLATES SPATES SPALES SPALTS SPELTS SWELTS SWEETS

> 11 jumps

Comment: I don't believe 'spelts' is a word. The plural of spelt is spelt and I can't find it in any of the main dictionaries

Comment: Its a kind of wheat in plural

Comment: No, thats what I'm saying. The plural of 'spelt' as in the wheat is just spelt and not spelts. Its like sheep or fish, you don't add 's' on the end. [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelt) its reffered to as spelt and never spelts

Comment: Go to wiktionary

Comment: Noun Edit
spelt (usually uncountable, plural spelts)

A grain, considered either a subspecies of wheat, Triticum aestivum subsp. spelta, or a separate species Triticum spelta or Triticum dicoccon

Comment: Nice try though hehe

Comment: It may be allowed, I guess it depends on the dictionary. But as no dictionary is specified here, then it will probably be ok

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil you do add the suffix when you use the singular to mean "a species or variety of". For example: "Some fishes eat algae." Linguistically, (if not scientifically) I'd be quite ok with "Most spelts are now extinct."

Comment: @Bass well I guess I stand corrected then :)